# Installing release apk – which version should flutter install?

Tags: flutter

After I build release apk there are three different apk in project `release` folder (app-arm64-v8a-release.apk, app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk, app-x86_64-release.apk). In addition, there is an apk file named `app.apk` in `apk` folder (above the `release` folder level).

When I run

> flutter install

the output is

> Installing app.apk to [android device]...
>
> Uninstalling old version...
>
> Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...                                  2,0s

And, as you can see now, flutter installs the `app.apk` which is the same size as `app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk`, so I suppose those files are the same file. But the target android device supports `arm64-v8a` instructions, so why in this case flutter installs apk based an `armeabi-v7a` instructions set?

Comment: How did you build the release apk?
If you are trying to release app to playstore, try using flutter build appbundle

Comment: @Vamsi I used `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`. This app is not intended for playstore yet so appbundle is not an option.

Comment: i know it's late but just in case there are people looking for the same case, you guys can try to rename the abi version you want to install to ```app.apk```